# Chef not found on Vagrant box during provisioning, but exists on machine

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-zero

I am attempting to use chef zero through vagrant as a stepping stone to understanding it. However, I seem to be stumbling out of the gate. When provisioning, I get a message that clearly says chef has been installed before receiving an error saying it cannot be found.

```
==> default: Thank you for installing Chef!
==> default: Running provisioner: chef_zero...
==> default: Detected Chef (latest) is already installed
The chef binary (either `chef-solo` or `chef-client`) was not found on
the VM and is required for chef provisioning. Please verify that chef
is installed and that the binary is available on the PATH.
```

But, when I `vagrant ssh` I can clearly see chef when I tab complete

```
[vagrant@vagrant-centos5 ~]$ cd /usr/bin/chef-
chef-apply   chef-client  chef-shell   chef-solo
```

And you can see that /usr/bin is in my path

```
[vagrant@vagrant-centos5 ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/vagrant/bin
```

However I notice no chef-zero on my vagrant machine, a fact that I am suspicious of despite it not being a part of the actual error. I can run chef-zero on my host machine, and have tried that, but it does not seem to make a difference.

I have the following vagrant plugins installed:

```
whtevn@test-app$ vagrant plugin list
vagrant-berkshelf (4.0.3)
vagrant-cachier (1.2.0)
vagrant-chef-zero (0.7.1)
vagrant-hostmanager (1.5.0)
vagrant-omnibus (1.4.1)
vagrant-share (1.1.3, system)
```

and, just for good measure

```
whtevn@test-app$ vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.7.2
```

Has anyone seen something like this? My next step is to try to manually install chef-zero on the VM and try to provision again. But, I'm shooting in the dark, so I figured I would ask

Comment: What version of Chef is installed (`chef-client --version`)? I also notice you're running CentOS 5... is that correct?

Comment: CentOS 5 is what I was running, that is correct. Thank you for pointing that out. I can't say for certain whether it was upgrading to 6 (I had accidentally instally 5.6 instead of 6.5...so stupid), or uninstalling the entire chef constellation of applications and then starting again with chef-zero specifically in mind, but it seems to be working now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you please post the content of your `Vagrantfile` ?